# Setting up different droppable area in one canvas HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, canvas, fabricjs

I want to have different droppable area in one canvas, an example can be seen on this link http://custom.case-mate.com/diy?bypassLandingPage=true#design/iphone5_barelythere
I want to drag and drop images on to different portions of the same canvas.

after checking the link, can anybody tell me how they have done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do first is to define the regions in an array that you want to use as drop zones locally on the canvas.

From there it is simply check the mouse client position that you receive in the drop event adjusted for the canvas:

```js
/// some random regions to check against
regions = [[0, 0, 100, 100],
           [120, 50, 100, 100],
           [30, 230, 100, 100],
           [300,300,100,100]],

/// this is used to adjust mouse pos. later
rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), ...
```

Setup canvas to handle drop events:

```js
canvas.addEventListener('dragover', fileDragOver, false);
canvas.addEventListener('drop',     fileSelect,   false);
```

When you now drop files to the canvas you can check everything - here we draw a random fill color for the region the file(s) where dropped at (if any):

```js
function fileSelect(e) {

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    /// adjust mouse position relative to canvas       
    var x = e.clientX - rect.left,
        y = e.clientY - rect.top;

    /// iterate the regions
    for(i = 0; r = regions[i]; i++) {

        /// are mouse in a region?
        if (x >= r[0] && x < r[0] + r[2] &&
            y >= r[1] && y < r[1] + r[3]) {

            /// if so, fill that region
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' +
                parseInt(255 * Math.random(), 10) + ',' +
                parseInt(255 * Math.random(), 10) + ',' +
                parseInt(255 * Math.random(), 10) + ',' +
                '0.5)';

            ctx.fillRect(r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3]);

            /// ... do something else
            breaK;
        }
    }
```

}

Here is a working example (drop some files on the boxes):

<kbd>**[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/spnhT/)**</kbd>